# Browser 'sessionStorage' not getting on another page

Tags: jquery, html, web-storage

I am trying to make a `cart` using `web storage` in `google chrome`. I have too pages `index.html` and `cart.html`. I can set the values from `index.html` and get it from the same page. But  when I move to `cart.html`, the stored values cant access there. Why it happens? I didn't get much tutorials about this. Please help.

My pages are

**index.html**

```
<html>
 <head>
    <title>Cart test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    sessionStorage.setItem( "total", 10 );
    var has_cart = 0;
    if(sessionStorage.length > 1){
        has_cart = sessionStorage.length -1;
    }
    console.log(sessionStorage);
    $(window).ready(function(){
        $('#cart-size').val(has_cart);
    }); 
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="custom.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <button type="button" data-id="1" product="1" merchant="1" class="add-cart">Add 1</button>
    <button type="button" data-id="1" product="2" merchant="1" class="add-cart">Add 2</button>
    <button type="button" data-id="1" product="3" merchant="2" class="add-cart">Add 3</button>
    <br /><br />
    <input type="text" size="3" id="cart-size" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <a href="cart.html">Go to cart</a>
 </body>
</html>
```

**cart.html**

```
<html>
    <head>    
        <title>Cart</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var has_cart = 0;
        if(sessionStorage.length > 1){
            has_cart = sessionStorage.length -1 ;
        }
        console.log(sessionStorage);
        $(window).ready(function(){
            $('#cart-size').val(has_cart);
        }); 
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="custom.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" size="3" id="cart-size" />
        <br />
        <br />
    </body>
</html>
```

**custom.js**

```
$(function(){
    $('.add-cart').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var elm = $(this);
        var id = elm.attr('data-id');
        var product = elm.attr('product');
        var merchant = elm.attr('merchant');
        cart = {
            item: product,
            id: id,
            mer: merchant
        };
        var jsonStr = JSON.stringify( cart );
        var cartValue = sessionStorage.getItem( product+id+merchant );
        var cartObj = JSON.parse( cartValue );
        if(cartObj){
            alert('Product already added to cart');
        }
        else
        {
            $('#cart-size').val(parseInt($('#cart-size').val())+1);
            sessionStorage.setItem( product+id+merchant, jsonStr );
        }
    });
});
```

I can't figure out the issue as there is not much helpful documentation in the web. Someone please help. Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sessionStorage` works like global variables. It loses its scope when you change page or close tab.

Use `localStorage` instead.

[Read more details here.](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But still it works like the same as before.. :(

Answer (score 1):

As told by Hiral `sessionStorage` loses its scope as the page is changed or tabs are closed . You have a better way to do this using JSTORAGE it is a easy and better way to store data and retreive them using its key

STORING DATA :
**set(key, value[, options])**

`$.jStorage.set(key, value, options);`

RETREIVING DATA :

**get(key[, default])**

```
value = $.jStorage.get(key)
value = $.jStorage.get(key, "default value")
```

DELETING DATA :

**deleteKey(key)**

```
$.jStorage.deleteKey(key)
```

You just need to add the cdn and either use jquery with json for storing and retreiving the data.
To put it in simple terms it is a local database which is supported in  all major browsers - **Internet Explorer 6+, Firefox 2+, Safari 4+, Chrome 4+, Opera 10.50+**

For further reference go check [`HERE`](http://www.jstorage.info/)

Comment: The link is outdated. Check GitHub instead: https://github.com/andris9/jStorage